Defender XDR KQL Function that converts query results to markdown doesn't work
I created this saved function in MDE Advanced Hunting (saved as TableToMarkdown) that is intended to convert ingested query results into markdown language:
let TableToMarkdown = (T:(*)) {
    let schema = T | getschema;
    let headers = schema | project ColumnName | summarize make_list(ColumnName) | extend String = strcat('| ', strcat_array(list_ColumnName, ' | '), ' |') | project String, Order=1;
    let upperDivider = schema | project ColumnName, Sep = '---' | summarize Cols=make_list(Sep) | extend String = strcat('| ', strcat_array(Cols, ' | '), ' |') | project String, Order=2;
    let data = T | extend Cols=pack_array(*) | extend String = strcat('| ', strcat_array(Cols, ' | '), ' |') | project String, Order=3;
    headers 
    | union upperDivider
    | union data
    | order by Order asc 
    | summarize Rows=make_list(String) 
    | project array_strcat(Rows, '\r\n')
}

Sample output:
| Timestamp | DeviceName | ActionType | AdditionalFields |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-07-22T01:18:08.0515724Z | MyHostName | UsbDriveMounted | {"DriveLetter":"D:","BusType":7,"ProductName":"CDDVDW GP70N    ","ProductRevision":"RR01","SerialNumber":"ABCDEFG123","Manufacturer":"hp","Volume":"\\\\?\\Volume{270-02-11b-92-863}","LoggedOnUsers":["USERNAME"]} |
| 2024-07-22T13:03:57.4174787Z | MyHostName | UsbDriveMounted | {"DriveLetter":"E:","BusType":7,"ProductName":"DVDRAM GP65NB60 ","ProductRevision":"PF00","SerialNumber":"ABCDEFG124","Manufacturer":"HL-DT-ST","Volume":"\\\\?\\Volume{2a0-3d-df3-11-3f4}","LoggedOnUsers":["USERNAME"]} |

The intent is to use it by piping query results into the function, like so:
let Sus_HostName = 'MyHostName';
DeviceEvents
    | where DeviceName has Sus_HostName
    | where ActionType contains "USB"
    | invoke TableToMarkdown()

However, I keep running into this error whenever I run that query, or add | invoke TableToMarkdown() to any query:

Syntax error


Error message
Expected: ;
How to resolve
Fix syntax errors in your query
Token
}
Line
1
Position
2

The only way I can get the function to work is to store the query as a variable and include the entire function in the query, like so:
let Sus_HostName = 'MyHostName';
let t = DeviceEvents
    | where DeviceName has Sus_HostName
    | where ActionType contains "USB";
let schema = t | getschema;
let headers = schema | project ColumnName | summarize make_list(ColumnName) | extend String = strcat('| ', strcat_array(list_ColumnName, ' | '), ' |') | project String, Order=1;
let upperDivider = schema | project ColumnName, Sep = '---' | summarize Cols=make_list(Sep) | extend String = strcat('| ', strcat_array(Cols, ' | '), ' |') | project String, Order=2;
let data = t | extend Cols=pack_array(*) | extend String = strcat('| ', strcat_array(Cols, ' | '), ' |') | project String, Order=3;
headers 
    | union upperDivider
    | union data
    | order by Order asc 
    | summarize Rows=make_list(String) 
    | project array_strcat(Rows, '\r\n')

 
I'm kinda new to Defender XDR so this is making my head spin.  What am I doing wrong or not understanding?  For simplicity's sake, I would like to be able to just add | invoke TableToMarkdown() or something similar to the ends of my queries if at all possible.

AFAIK, the markdown might not be possible in KQL. you might need to hardcode or store it in the variable.
